# How to delete footer(buttons) in screen Flow using LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have 2 lwc components( overrall view doesnt seem to be professional,because I still have buttons from footer)

I cannot just hide them from flow,because they are being used.
I want my flow to work with my custom buttons(for creation).
Maybe someone can give me suggestions or links for the info?

My code:
1st lwc for acc creation:

***html***

```
  <template>
       <lightning-card title="Create and View Account Record">
          <div class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
        
            <lightning-record-form 
            object-api-name="Account" 
            record-id={accountRecordId}
            columns="2" 
            mode="edit" 
            fields={arrayFields}
            onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
        </lightning-record-form>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

***js***

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import {FlowNavigationNextEvent} from 'lightning/flowSupport';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class AccountCreation extends LightningElement {

    @api availableActions = [];
    @api accountRecordId;
    arrayFields = ['Name', 'AccountNumber', 'Phone', 'Type', 'Website'];
    handleSuccess(event){
        this.accountRecordId = event.detail.id;
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
         title: "Record created " + this.accountRecordId,
         message: "Account is created",
         variant:"success"

        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        this.handleGoNext();
}
handleGoNext(){
    //check if NEXT is allowed on this screen
    if(this.availableActions.find(action => action === 'NEXT')){
        //navigate to next screen
        const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
        this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
}
}
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Account Creation Component</masterLabel>
    <description>This is a simple component</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>

    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="accountRecordId" type="String" label="Current Account Id" 
                        description="Id of the current record"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

2nd lwc for contact creation:

**html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title={cardTitle}>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                <lightning-messages>
                </lightning-messages>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Name">
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" value={recordId}>
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Title">
                </lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-button
                        class="slds-m-top_small"
                        type="submit"
                        label="Create new">
                    </lightning-button>
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**js**

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class ContactCreationLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    cardTitle='New Contact';
    
    handleSuccess (){
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Success!",
            message: "The Contact's record has been successfully saved.",
            variant: "success",
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
 <masterLabel>Contact Card</masterLabel>
    <description>This component shows the new contact record form.</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Account</object>
            </objects>         
        </targetConfig>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Current Account Id" 
                        description="Id of the current record"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't uncheck the buttons in flow configuration like below, if need next & finish functionality why don't implement in lwc level.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,I will try to implement in lwc level.